# can i go back to USA with as tourist even after living there illegally for 10 years?

Tags: visas, overstaying

i am a 34 year old mexican. when i was a minor(14 years old), i entered the USA with a tourist visa in 1995,but stayed 10 years illegally in that country. During that time, I went to middle school, high school, and graduatated from a community college. I started working at the age of 18. I paid taxes as well every year.
In the year 2005, I willingly returned to my home country, mexico. I have been living in mexico for over ten years now , and I have not been back to the usa, neither have I had any trouble with the law in mexico nor usa.
I would like to go back to the USA to visit friends, and return to mexico. I am a teacher in mexico. I have been working as a teacher since I returned from the usa. My reason for asking for advice is because I would like to know if there’s a chance I be given a visa to visit the usa even with the circumstances I mentioned above. Please help.

Comment: While you were in the U.S., did you ever claim to anybody that you were a U.S. citizen?

Comment: I have trouble understanding these (types) of questions. Apply for a visa. If you get it, you're golden. If not, you'll know. The only thing I would add beyond that is advice, don't lie. Anywhere. On any form.

Answer (score 1):

From what you said, you shouldn't have an unlawful presence ban. If you don't have any other ban, which it doesn't sound like you have, it's possible you will get a visa. Just because it's possible doesn't mean you will get it. We don't know how the consular officer will think. Do you have strong ties to Mexico? Your history of overstay will hurt your chances.

Comment: i have my famly here. i am getting my house, i got my permanent job as a teacher here, my partner